# How to find out if everything in a set of objects has meets a criteria in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Suppose have a CmdLet called Get-SomeResource. It takes a path and returns an array of Resource objects. The resource object has two properties an ID and Value. I want to read in a load of paths from a CSV call Get-SomeResource on each and write to a new CSV the Path and a boolean indicating whether all the resources returned for that path have a non null Value.

So far I have this but I don't know what to put where the comment is:

```
Import-Csv file.csv -ParameterVariable Row `
| Get-SomeResource `
| Select @{N='Path';E={$Row.Path}},@{N='AllResourcesHaveAValue';@{E={<# What goes here? #>}} `
| Export-Csv new-file.csv
```

I tried putting `$_ -ne $null` where the comment is but that tells me if the array is null a not whether the Values of the items within are null. If I put `$_.Value -ne $null` is that going to return true or false if have the items have a null value and half don't, or is it just going to tell me if the first or last item has a null value?

Comment: The answers to your questions depend on whether `Get-SomeResource` outputs its array non-enumerated or not...

Comment: It is not enumerated at present. It is written by passing the array to WriteObject without setting enumerateCollection. I have the code for Get-SomeResource so I could change that if it is going to make my life easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use the [intrinsic `.Where({})` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.4#where) to test each object in the collection returned by `Get-SomeResource`:

```
...| Select ...,@{N='AllResourcesHaveAValue';E={ $_.Where({$null -eq $_.Value}, 'First').Count -eq 0 }}
```

Here, the `.Where({$null -ne $_.Value}, 'First')` expression will return a collection of length 1 if *any* object in the collection satisfies `$null -eq $_.Value` - otherwise 0.

Answer (score 0):

To offer an alternative to [Mathias' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77941869/45375):

A simpler and on average likely faster solution is to use [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration); however, it potentially consumes more memory, given that it involves enumeration *all* elements of the input collection; that said, unless the the input collection is large, that probably won't matter:

- If the objects contained in your `$_` array are *of the same type* and therefore *always have a `.Value` property*, whose *value* may situationally be `$null`:

  ```bash
  ... @{ N= 'AllResourcesHaveAValue'; E={ $null -notin $_.Value } }
  ```

  - `$null` values stored in *existing* properties of the objects in the input collection *are* reported as part of the array of returned values, so the [`-in` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-in-and--notin) can be used to test for the presence of at least one `$null`.
- If, by contrast, the objects may be of differing types, and you want to detect if there are objects that *do not have a `.Value` property at all*:

  ```bash
  ... @{ N= 'AllResourcesHaveAValue'; E={ @($_.Value).Count -eq $_.Count } }
  ```

  - Objects that do not have the property being enumerated do *not* contribute to the array of values returned, so the count of returned values being equal to the count of objects in the input collection implies that all objects in the latter *do* have a `.Value` property.
  - That said, a *bug* - still present as of PowerShell 7.4.1 - makes `[pscustomobject]` instances unexpectedly contribute `$null` even if they do *not* have the property being enumerated - see [GitHub issue #13752](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13752).
- To *combine* the two tests, so as to count only non-`$null` values:

  ```bash
  ... @{ N= 'AllResourcesHaveAValue'; E={ (@($_.Value) -ne $null).Count -eq $_.Count } }
  ```

  - This filters out actual `$null` values from existing property values (using the array-filtering properties of comparison operators such as `-ne`) and therefore counts only existing values that aren't `$null`.